# how to prevent focusout to generate an additional change event on text input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to prevent focusing out to create an additional change event on a text input field.

I validate the form as I type in the text input filed using keyup(), and change() events when hit enter using ajax.

When I click on save button it goes and validates the form once again and if OK saves the form to database.

Problem happens when I type on the text field, leave the cursor there and click on the save button. This first generates change event (because of focusout) and validates the form, since save was clicked it saves once, then save button click event is executed and this saves the form once again.

HTML

```
<form id="scheduling" name="scheduling" method="post">
    <div id="prodSchedContainer">
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="inputText" id="tInput-1" class="testInputField">
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" id="saveButton-scheduling" name="saveButton" class="sharedButton saveButton" title="Save">
</form>
```

JS:

```
$('#prodSchedContainer').on('change', '.testInputField', function () {
    infoLine = 'TEST INPUT CHANGED:    >>>>>     id: ' + $(this).attr('id') + '     >>>>>     ' + $(this).val();
    renderInfoBox(infoLine);
    performScheduleValidation($(this));
});

$('#prodSchedContainer').on('keyup', '.testInputField', function () {
    infoLine = 'TEST INPUT KEYUP:    >>>>>     id: ' + $(this).attr('id') + '     >>>>>     ' + $(this).val();
    renderInfoBox(infoLine);
    performScheduleValidation($(this));
});


$('#schedulingContainer').on('click', '.saveButton', function () {
    infoLine = 'SAVING SCHEDULE:    >>>>>     id:' + $(this).attr('id') + '     >>>>>     ' + 'WHAT:' +     $(this).attr('what') + '   / TYPE:' + $(this).attr('apptType') + ' / APPT:' + $(this).attr('appt') + '      >>>>>    ' + $(this).val();
    renderInfoBox(infoLine);
    performScheduleValidation($(this));
});

function performScheduleValidation(sObj) {
    objID = $(sObj).attr('id');
    if (objID == 'saveButton-scheduling') {
        action = 'save';
    } else {
        action = 'validate';
    }
    valData.push(['action', action]);
    valData.push(['formData', formData]);

    var ajaxData = JSON.stringify(valData);
    var URL = BASE_DIR + 'schedulingValidation.php';

    $.ajax({
        url: URL,
        type: 'POST',
        data: { data: ajaxData },
        success: function (theResponse) {
            var responseData = $.parseJSON(theResponse);
            isValid = responseData['valid'][0];
            if (!isSaved) { //---   If the Schedule is not Saved
                //  Do some stuff within the form
            } else {    //---   The Schedule Is saved   ----------  /
                $('#schedulingContainer').html('');         //----  Clear up the scheduling container       /
                $('#product_idx_selector').val(0);
                count_db_table('ota_scheduling');
            }
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('Error: ' + errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

PHP:

```
require_once("includes/connection.php");
require_once("/includes/functions.php");
$lang  = $_SESSION['Language'];

$data = json_decode($_POST['data']);

$action         = $data[0][1];
// ---- More Data
$weeklySchedule = $data[9][1];
$objID          = $data[10][1];

//---   Validation Part
$schVal = 1;    // This is 1 or 0 depending on the validation calculations

//---   SAVING Part
if ($action == 'save' && $objID=='saveButton-scheduling' && $schVal == 1) {
    $query  = "INSERT INTO ota_scheduling ( ";
    $query .= "product_idx, ";
    $query .= "trainers, ";
    $query .= "coupons ";
    $query .= ") ";

    $query .= "VALUES ( ";
    $query .= $productRow['id'] . ", ";
    $query .= "'".$multiAppointments[0]['trainers'] . "', ";
    $query .= "'".$multiAppointments[0]['coupons'] . "' ";
    $query .= " )";

    $result = mysql_query($query, $connection);
    if(!$result) { 
        die("Database query failed at 'schedulingValidation.php' while Adding a Parent Schedule @ ota_scheduling: " . mysql_error());
    } else { 
        $parentID = mysql_insert_id();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your code for validating and saving?  That would help us better understand what is happening and how to help.

Comment: The code is really long. But this is a default JS behavior, losing focus generates a automatic change event. I need to prevent that. I will update the post with shorten version of the code.

Comment: I don't know any other ways to prevent onchange apart from `Event.prototype.preventDefault` (which would still require it to be triggered) so why instead of saving on the `onchange` you save when the enter key is pressed or when the save button is clicked?

Comment: onchange I validate (enter, or keyup). The problem happens when user types in the filed leaves the cursor there, and click on the save button. This triggers first 'change' than 'blur' on the input field, after that triggers click on save. I suppose when the script gets the event 'click' on button, it is already to late, because change on input already is fired.

Comment: Based on this code, it appears to me that you validate onKeyUp and onChange and save on button click, thus, your problematic sequence of events generates an extra call to validate, but only one save call.  Since you are executing AJAX onKeyUp, you should probably have a way to cancel the AJAX call and/or a timeout before it is sent since typing quickly will generate a lot of calls. Also, AJAX calls may not return in order.  Since onchange only fires on focus out for text boxes, do you need the onchange event at all?

Comment: Thank you for you comment Loren. My code is a bit more complicated, I have just simplified it here for diagnostics reasons. The text box has a date time picker underneath, and each time you choose a date or time slot it creates a change event. But when the user picks new time and date and immediately clicks on save button, because of the extra focusout change event, it saves twice. I found a solution that I am not too comfortable with. I put half second timeout on the save button fire. That gives enough time for the change event. I think I need to separate the validate and save functions.